# How to create controller and views for has_many and through relationship in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

please go easy on me as I'm just a beginner, I am breaking my head on this issue for the past 2 days now. To summarize, I have a user and productplan , when a user selects a certain product plan(radiobutton or checkbox) , I want the current user id and selected product id to be stored in the join table called userproducts 
But for some reason I could not store the data , I have no clue where I am going wrong, any help appreciated, thanks.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userproducts
  has_many :productplans, :through=>:userproducts
end

class productplan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :userproducts
  has_many :users, :through => :userproducts
end

class Userproduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :productplan
end
```

ProductPlan Controllers:

```
class ProductPlanController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
def new 
    @user=User.new
  end  
end

def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render :action => 'index'
  else
    render :action =>'new'
  end
private 
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:productplan_ids => [])
end
end
```

Views:
productplan/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user,:url=> productplan_index_path,:method => :post do 
|f|%>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :productplan_ids, ProductPlan.all, :id, 
:productplan_name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Since there are less examples on the controller and views regarding has_many through I am pretty sure I have many mistakes in it. Also when I try submitting the form I get this log:

```
enterStarted POST "/Productplan" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-28 11:08:29 -0600
Processing by ProductPlanController#create as HTML
Parameters 
{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>
"mi9RwHCLPKItXai67t5iX0RYrDoE6TN9T
iZzJFYELbKVDlHbhpeNmOC0q2gu1iXyWNaUqGSEsPrBEjcUSE2yYw==", "user"= >
{"productsku_ids"=>["", "4", "7"]}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ProductPlan Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans" WHERE 
"productplans"."id" IN (4, 7)
(0.5ms)  BEGIN
Provider Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers" WHERE 
"providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE Provider Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "providers".* FROM "providers" WHERE 
"providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendering ups/new.html.erb within layouts/application
ProductPlan Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans"
Rendered productplans/_form.html.erb (4.6ms)
Rendered productplans/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
Rendered _navbar.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 191ms (Views: 102.1ms | ActiveRecord: 14.6ms) here
```

For some reason it rollbacks,also I need to get the current user too.

```
dependent_new GET    /dependent/new(.:format)              dependent#new
    dependent_create GET    /dependent/create(.:format)           dependent#create
        summary_root GET    /summary/index(.:format)              summary#index
          home_plans GET    /home/plans(.:format)                 home#plans
              thanks GET    /thanks(.:format)                     charges#thanks
  authenticated_root GET    /                                     home#roothome
    productplan_index GET    /productplan(.:format)                 productplan#index
                     POST   /productplan(.:format)                 productplan#create
      new_productplan GET    /productplan/new(.:format)             productplan#new
     edit_productplan GET    /productplan/:id/edit(.:format)        productplan#edit
          productplan GET    /productplan/:id(.:format)             productplan#show
                     PATCH  /productplan/:id(.:format)             productplan#update
                     PUT    /productplan/:id(.:format)             productplan#update
                     DELETE /productplan/:id(.:format)             productplan#destroy
        userproducts GET    /userproducts(.:format)               userproducts#index
                     POST   /userproducts(.:format)               userproducts#create
     new_userproduct GET    /userproducts/new(.:format)           userproducts#new
    edit_userproduct GET    /userproducts/:id/edit(.:format)      userproducts#edit
         userproduct GET    /userproducts/:id(.:format)           userproducts#show
                     PATCH  /userproducts/:id(.:format)           userproducts#update
                     PUT    /userproducts/:id(.:format)           userproducts#update
                     DELETE /userproducts/:id(.:format)           userproducts#destroy
                 ups POST   /ups(.:format)                        ups#create
              new_up GET    /ups/new(.:format)                    ups#new
                root GET    /                                     home#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)             devise/sessions#destroy
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit
       user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
                     POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create
```

SO I modified my as per @jvillian told to ,but the problem still persists,here is my new code.
Please note I renamed user products to ups,

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :ups
 has_many :productplans, through: :ups
end

class productplan < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :ups
 has_many :users, :through => :ups
end

class Up < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :productplan
end
```

Ups Controller:

```
class UpsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def create
 current_user.productplans<<Productplan.where(id: productplans_ids)
 render :action => 'index'
end

private

def productplan_ids
 params.require(:up).permit(productplan_ids:[])
end
end
```

Views ups/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :up,:url=> ups_path do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :productplan_ids, Productplan.all, :id, 
:productplan_name %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/ups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-28 14:43:50 -0600
Processing by UpsController#index as HTML
User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering ups/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Productplan Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans"
Rendered ups/_form.html.erb (42.5ms)
Rendered ups/index.html.erb within layouts/application (47.7ms)
Rendered _navbar.html.erb (0.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 347ms (Views: 235.0ms | ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)


Started POST "/ups" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-28 14:43:53 -0600
Processing by UpsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"g7lLydleU7J14G7N9avWSK87E4BbkPQ9sdL
Q9X2bbSCMmEvSL0LiiLgJbR81o5Hls7UrEjv9d7o+5pTFY9Ly8Q==", "up"=>
{"productplan_ids"=>["", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save Up"}
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Productplan Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans" WHERE 
"productplans"."id" = $1  [["id", nil]]
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
Rendering ups/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Productplan Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans"
Rendered ups/_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
Rendered ups/index.html.erb within layouts/application (7.9ms)
Rendered _navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 201ms (Views: 183.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

route.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
# write all your routes inside this block
resources :productplan
resources :ups
end
```

There is still no data inserted in the Ups table , no error as well. Although according to log file it doesnt rollback but still the issue persists.

Comment: your form_for url seems incorrect `<%= form_for @user,:url=> productplan_index_path 
`, it should be the create action not the index action

Comment: Why your ProductPlanController has methods for User resource. It should be a controller for ProductPlan. It make no sense to me

Comment: I fear this code is too broken to fix.

Comment: @xeon131 I use the index path because by running rake routes i get productplan_index GET    /productplan(.:format)                 productplan#index
                         POST   /productplan(.:format)                 productplan#create

Comment: @MatiasSeguel Hi !! Are you suggesting to create a separate controller for user??

Comment: @jvillian Thats right , I need to fix it right away or any way I can start from new

Comment: I don't think it's too bad for a beginner. can you add your rake routes output in your questio?. I cannot understand it in the comments.

Comment: As @jvillian has pointed out ProductPlanController is doing the work of your UsersController. please refactor, after figuring out this issue.

Comment: @xeon131 As you mentioned I have updated my post and added a list of routes , and sure I will take a look at the controller and add a UserController as well and try it.

Comment: Which controller action renders `productplan/_form.html.erb`?

Comment: @jvillian it should be  `new_productplan GET    /productplan/new(.:format)             productplan#new`

Comment: Can you change your form url to `new_productplan_path` and try if it works

Comment: @jvillian the new action renders the partial form , but I tried replacing my url with new_productplan_path and after clicking the submit button, it gave me a routing error "No route matches [POST] "/productplan/new" .

Comment: @xeon131 the new action renders the partial form , but I tried replacing my url with new_productplan_path and after clicking the submit button, it gave me a routing error "No route matches [POST] "/productplan/new" .

Comment: oops, sorry. It should be `productplan_path`. (Its 1 am here and I am feeling sleepy)

Comment: please remove the `new` action from your controller. It is not being used anywhere and it is doing nothing.

Comment: @xeon131 if I remove the new action controller , it gives an  Argument error saying  "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty", also if i remove the "url" code it asks for a path to provide.

Comment: sorry, I am giving bad advice now. please keep that action. it is rendering your form apparently  .I will look into this tomorrow if it's still unresolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: AFTER CODE MODIFICATIONS FROM OP

Much closer!

As you can see here:

```
Productplan Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "productplans".* FROM "productplans" WHERE "productplans"."id" = $1  [["id", nil]]
```

we didn't get `productplan_ids` quite right (as indicated by `nil`). If, in console, you do:

```
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(up: {productplan_ids: ["","4"]})
> params.require(:up).permit(productplan_ids: [])
 => {"productplan_ids"=>["", "4"]}
```

you can see that the `productplan_ids` method is returning a `hash` (well, not exactly, but close enough for now). But, you want the value for the `:productplan_ids` key. So, try:

```
def productplan_ids
  params.require(:up)[:productplan_ids]
end
```

Which should give you:

```
> params.require(:up)[:productplan_ids]
 => ["", "4"]
```

the `array` you're looking for.

ORIGINAL ANSWER

I'm going to take a swing at this, but it's going to be tough.

Okay, let's assume:

- You have a logged in user that is available through `current_user` in your `create` action (it looks like you're using Devise?)
- You have already created your `ProductPlans`
- In `routes.rb`, you have `resources :user_products` (not `userproducts`, see note later on...)

Your `form_for` should look like:

```
<%= form_for :user_product, user_products_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :product_plan_ids, ProductPlan.all, :id, :product_plan_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Note: You can use the symbol `:user_product` instead of the instance variable `@user` because you're not basing any form fields on `@user`.

Note: A form automatically does a `post`, so you don't need to specify `method`.

Then, `UserProductsController` (not `ProductPlanController` since you're creating one or more `user_products` not `product_plans`) should look something like:

```
class UserProductsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    current_user.product_plans << ProductPlan.where(id: product_plan_ids)
    render action: some_success_condition ? 'index' : 'new'
  end

  private

  def product_plan_ids
    params.require(:user_product).permit(product_plan_ids: [])
  end

end
```

Note: You probably don't need a `new` action because you don't really need to instantiate anything (at least not based on anything you've shown).

Note: You'll need to sort out what `some_success_condition` is. But it's certainly not `@user.save`. Because you're creating `user_products`, not a `user`.

ALSO, You say:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:productplan_ids => [])
```

But your params are:

```
{
  ...,
  "user"=> {
    "productsku_ids"=>["", "4", "7"]
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Create User"
}
```

You permit `productplan_ids` (should be `product_plan_ids`), but have `productsku_ids` (should be `product_sku_ids`) in your params.

Some other things:

You should read through the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) to get your naming correct.

Class names should be CamelCase. So, `ProductPlan`, not `Productplan`.

Symbols and variables should be SnakeCase. So, :user_products, not :userproducts.

Controller names should be plural, not singular, if they are resource-oriented. So, `ProductPlansController`, not `ProductPlanController`. (I assume you have all the usual RESTful actions for `ProductPlan`, like `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, etc.)

AND, it's more conventional these days to do `through: :user_products` than `:through => :user_products`.

So:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_products
  has_many :product_plans, through: :user_products
end

class ProductPlan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_products
  has_many :users, through: :user_products
end

class UserProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product_plan
end
```

Also, you have a bunch of mis-matched `def ... end` statements:

```
class ProductPlanController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new 
      @user=User.new
    end  
  end # <= extra 'end' here

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action =>'new'
    end
  # <= missing 'end' here

  private 

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:productplan_ids => [])
  end

end
```

I assume that's some sort of copy-paste error

I have no idea why you're doing:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render :action => 'index'
  else
    render :action =>'new'
  end
end
```

In your `ProductPlansController`. It's `ProductPlansController`. It should create a `ProductPlan`, not a `User`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the post , I will definitely try this , also FYI , I have naming errors because I have edited from my original code as the namings are complicated and I didnt want to confuse anyone, for example ProductPlan is actually Productsku in my original code.but thanks so much I will try this and get back to you.CHeers.

Comment: Ok so I did what you told to,created a new controller and cleaned the code as much as possible but still there is no insertion of data in the join table. I will posting the new code soon

Comment: I updated the post with your code in it please do take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer (with new stuff at the top). I think you're quite close.

Comment: OHHH DAMNNN...Thanks so much , that was very helpful , I could finally get it working. The data stores successfully in table.You sir deserve a salute, saved me a hell of  a headache... :-) Thanks again.Cheers.

Comment: Fantastic! Now, promise me, you'll clean up your naming! ;-)

Comment: Ya sure , definitely :-D